# Telephone Number is required field error message on Magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2

I have developed a Magento 2 site in which i am facing an issue some times not all the times. On checkout page once all process is don i face this issue.
[image: Billing and shipping address are the same]

if i check the checkbox of My Billing and shipping address are the same, the telephone number disapear below United Kingdom. Don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Is there available telephone number in your shipping address??? Telephone number is mandatory for both shipping and billing address